# Sync Feature of Coldfusion FTP

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I am using `cfftp` to get images from ftp server. As the image files can be very large. So the user has to wait very long.

Is there a way to create a progressbar for this ftp get files operation?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using CF9 or higher, you would want to harness the cfprogressbar tag.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec19562-7fdf.html

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe there is any built in way, but you could get emulate some type of completion tracking.

Start by running:
`cfftp action="listdir"`
http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_f_16.html

Get the File size and start or to a table in your database or other variable storage.

Then through an ajax script or iframe have another script continuously run:
`cfdirectory action=list"` 
on your destination folder.

Compare your file sizes and then you can output the status in a percentage, progress meter, etc..